# Best practice for different translations of strings in python

Tags: python, json, xml, string, translation

I have to create a new project in Python. I want to know the best practice to set my project for handling multiple translations of strings. I know, for instance, that in Android we use a constant and a xml file in res/strings. We can set multiple xmls with different languages to have different translations.
Do we have a similar library to do the same in python? I'd like to have some files, idk maybe in xml or json, in which in each file I have the translation of all my string in a language (English, Italian, etc...)
Of course I can implement from scratch a class which does this, which map each constant to a string after parsed a json file, but is there something invented yet?

thank you

Comment: This link may help: https://docs.python.org/3/library/i18n.html

Comment: Thank you! After your suggestion I found this library very useful https://github.com/danhper/python-i18n